# how to auto focus editor on Xcode

Tags: xcode, vim, xcode8, xcode7

I am new on Xcode and crazy using vim mode for everything. On Xcode, whenever I switch to different tab on editor view I have to use keyboard shortcut `command + J` to show `move focus to editor` and click `enter` then continues to use vim. Is there any internal setting or another way for me to just focus on new tab file after switch different tab file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shows the one next to the current tab.